# Performance and Memory usage when Using std::string in Java JNI Programming

Tags: java, java-native-interface

```
const char* chr = env->GetStringUTFChars(myjstring, NULL);
std::string cstr(chr);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(myjstring, chr);
```

The same copy of a **string data** in the above code is
myjstring (copy 1)
chr (copy 2)
cstr (copy 3)    // string manipulation will be easy.

So to avoid one copy of string data, when writing Java JNI programming, will it be a best practice if one avoid using std::string in the above scenario and go with char*?.

Comment: It's not unlikely that `myjstring` contains a pointer to a zero-terminated string in it, and best-case scenario the `GetStringUTFChars` function plainly returns this pointer. This means that you will only have two copies of the string. As for "best practice", it's a very subjective matter, and also depends quite a lot on use-cases and what you're supposed to be doing with the string in the C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetString / ReleaseString don't necessarily make a copy.  They should create a reference ensuring java doesn't free the memory inadvertently.

The std::string constructor would get a (possibly truncated) - '\0' would stop the std::string from parsing the data view of the string.

So it would be a balance if the functionality offered by std::string gave more than the memory cost of the copy.  Typically it is not really different to

```
int function( std::string to_be_used ){
```

to_be_used is a new copy of the string, and would have (C++11>) a full copy of the data.